# Is apostrophe-s ('s) only for "is" and "has"?

Tags: verbs, contractions

I heard this dictation: "Well, we weren't sure. We were thinking the ride's going to start up again."

As a stenographer, my job is to transcribe. If I were to turn "ride's" into two words, would this be better written "ride was" or "ride is"?

Are there any examples where apostrophe-s ('s) is used to hide words other than "is" or "has"?

Comment: Surely if as a stenographer your job is to ***transcribe***, you should simply write what was said - i.e., ***ride's***. It shouldn't be your job to decide which tense the speaker *intended* (which might unreasonably influence other people's assessment of his linguistic competence, if they were to take the pedantic position that present tense was "uneducated" or "thoughtless").

Comment: The phrase "we were thinking" seems to be introducing a remembered thought. If so, this would be a quotation of the thought at the time, not their thinking now, and would mean: "We were thinking, *the ride is going to start up again.*"

Comment: I'm not aware of 's ever standing for ... was. But have you checked in say dictionaries? // Trivially, John's phaeton could be traced back to John[:] his phaeton, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Edwin: It wouldn't normally be *written* that way if the underlying verb is ***was***, but in many people's actual *speech*, the /w/ could be partially or completely eliminated. That's why I say it shouldn't be a stenographer's job to decide, since it might be totally irrelevant how good his/her hearing was.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Wouldn't that be "Johnnes phaeton", that is, a genitive suffix"? As I remember, the "John (his) phaeton" was a folk etymology.

Comment: @MετάEd Yes; I'm remembering the wrong answer. And I think it was a brougham John had, too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As a non-stenographer I personally don't know the assignment and whether it might involve unraveling all the strangeness of utterances. There's not just apostrophe to consider, but also self-repair, filler words, etc. I just can't say what this person's job is. And as a *strong* non-stenographer, you can't either.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, or a surrey. I seem to recall a fringe on top.

Comment: @MετάEd You're right again. Johnnes fringe was a sight to behold It's a great shame he went bald. (Actually, I must be hundreds of years out with these C19 carriages.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess you haven't seen Johnnes Tardis.

Comment: @MετάEd I'm so old I've seen Johnnes Tardwas.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see you, and raise you Johnnes Tardisgewesen.

Comment: I have to say, I'm impressed I haven't yet seen the word "type" in this conversation yet (reporters generally refer to their skill as writing rather than typing). But unfortunately people don't talk the way we are chatting right now. MetaEd put it nicely, "whether it might involve unraveling all the strangeness of utterances."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not clear whether you are asking about English or what you, as a transcriptionist, should do.

Comment: *'Twas the night before Christmas and all through the house, not a creature was stirring, not even a mouse*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s hard to know what’s going on in a person’s mind.

That being said, referring to Wikipedia's “[List of English contractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_English_contractions)”, apostrophe-s is found “in the wild” in contexts where it can represent *is*, *has*, *does*, or *us*. Of these, the only one that seems to make sense in English dialects that I recognize is *is*.

- We were thinking the ride *is* going to start up again.
- We were thinking the ride **has* going to start up again.
- We were thinking the ride **does* going to start up again.
- We were thinking the ride **us* going to start up again.

It is not normal for people to contract *was* to apostrophe-s. So this is unlikely to be what was meant.

- We were thinking the ride **was* going to start up again.

To put it another way, the phrase “we were thinking” introduces a remembered thought: a quotation or paraphrase of a thought at the time, not their thinking now. Adding punctuation to make this interpretation clear:

> We were thinking, “the ride *is* going to start up again”.

Comment: Also it should be vocally impossible for the person to say "the ride was" and sound like "the ride's", unless they are drunk or something like this that takes down every possible speech control.

Comment: Sure, but it should also be vocally impossible for a person to say "I am not" and sound like "I ain't", but it is. There is just no accounting for what can come out of somebody's mouth.

Comment: @JoaoArruda - I disagree.  It's quite common to contract "was" in speech.  If you listen closely it will probably sound a bit more like "uzz" than the "sss" sound of a contracted "is", but the contraction is still represented as *'s*.  Or else spelled out.  If this is a transcriptionist, and they have been instructed to "de-contract" such contractions, it's  their responsibility to listen closely to the actual sounds and determine which it it.

Comment: @HotLicks Can you document that it is common to contract "was" in speech? I've looked for references that would back this up but found none. And I personally have never heard it.

Comment: @MετάEd -  You've heard it thousands of times.  You just don't **hear** it, because your mind doesn't recognize it as a distinct representation.